# Sensor output intentionally coupled to its power supply net

Tags: amplifier, analog, instrumentation

Fellow EE's,

I've seen a couple of sensors using a coaxial cable connection where one terminal is both power supply to the sensor AND the sensor output itself(AC signal).
The manufacturer datasheet shows the following circuit as an example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBcych.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

May I ask for your input on the following:

1 - The sensor from this picture has a built-in preamp. What sort of circuit would be used on the preamp to power it and couple the sensor output on the same net without loading the passive filters connected to it?

2 - Is this a common technique? If it is, what's the name used on literature and troughout the industry?

Sensor info: [Datasheet](http://www.physicalacoustics.com/content/literature/sensors/Model_PK3I.pdf)

Comment: You might want to google the term phantom power

Comment: "without loading the passive filters connected to it?" - R1 *will* be loaded while providing the power for the sensor. "Is this a common technique?" - [1-Wire(TM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire) is another well-known implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically like an electret microphone: -

[image]

And inside you might find a jfet amplifier like this: -

[image]

Note that the 680R and 6k8 in the two diagrams can be any value between 680R and 10k (microphone dependent).

It may not use a jfet amplifier given the low resistance feed due to the 49R9 resistor. Electrets tend to use jfets because of the very high input impedance they have got. More than likely it's a single-transistor amplifier but could be a BJT - it all depends on what the actual sensing transducer is.

In industry, powered sensors tend to use separate pins for outputs but as this is likely to be a simple transistor amplifier there would be no reason to use three pins - it uses a method called phantom power.

Answer (score 0):

> What sort of circuit would be used on the preamp to power it and
>   couple the sensor output on the same net [...]?

Simple case, something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flAkX1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>